# Cannot disable SELinux in RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, selinux

I'm trying to disable SELinux in a rhel7 env installed on aws ec2 instance. I edited the `/etc/selinux/config` file and set `SELINUX=disabled` and then I rebooted the system. after the reboot I ran `sestatus` command and found it remains enabled:

```
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28
```

Any idea why its not changing?

Comment: is there a reason to disable it over putting it into permissive mode? I learned to work with SElinux after a while.  `cat` or `vi` your `/etc/sclinux/config`?

Comment: well I'm trying to install Greenplum and their recommendation is to disable it.

Comment: @Christopher how can I check it in GRUB?

Comment: @Christopher check grub.conf and it doesnt have any mention of selinux or enforcing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the problem.
the `/etc/selinux/config` file has SELINUX=enforcing before `SELINUX=disabled` defined which prevented to disable selinux so I commented `SELINUX=enforcing` and it worked

Comment: In the absence of any other answers, I'd advise that you accept your own answer. That way, the question appears as answered (and won't be listed when a user views unanswered questions).

Comment: done .. thanks @AnthonyGeoghegan for reminding me